# Свой Systray при «убитом» explorer.exe (доступ к контекстному меню)

Tags: windows

Доброго времени суток. Столкнулся с такой проблемой.

На рабочем компьютере нужно получить доступ к контекстному меню программы, которая по умолчанию попадает в системный трей (панель уведомлений). Но, т.к. на этом же компьютере отсутствует *shell*-оболочка, «Пуск», естественно, отсутствует.

Что посоветуете, чтобы получить доступ к пунктам меню программы?

В идеале требуется написать оконную программу, которая имеет соответствующие кнопки, имитирующие клик по соответствующему пункту контекстного меню.

Answer (score 1):

> Что посоветуете, чтобы получить доступ к пунктам меню программы?

использовать альтернативный *шелл* а-ля *rocketdock*.

Comment: ну, как вариант, согласен. Кстати, именно РокетДок вместо шелла и использую.

Comment: тут другого варианта нет! Как для простоты накодить windows form с твоей кнопкой и поставить его в реестре как шелл